# Can a web part read the SharePoint user id as a variable?

Tags: web-part

Can a web part read the SharePoint user id as a variable? I need to embed this within a url in the web part content. Thanks

Comment: check out the ``_spPageContextInfo`` global variable in the F12 DEV console

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint online (haven't tried it in SP 2013), you can use the following:

```
_spPageContextInfo.userId; and this will return the user ID
```

you can then take that and append your URL!